# Ayuda Nombre de usuario en Jtextfield

Tags: java, jtextfield

Necesito generar un "nickname" en base a 3 jtextfield, que tome las dos primeras letras de cada texto... por ejemplo

```
Juan
Perez
Gonzalez
```

y que el nick name sea

```
JUPEGO
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, ¿qué has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Puedes enseñar tu código? Te invito a visitar [ask] y [mcve]

Comment: Pues yo solo agarraría las dos primeras letras haciendo un substring() y eso ir metiendolo en una variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una vez que recuperaste el contenido de cada  jtextfield debes realizar un substring a cada variable. por ultimo le da aplicas un toUpperCase.

```
String nombre = "Juan";
String paterno = "Perez";
String materno = "Gonzalez";        
String nickname = (nombre.substring(0, 2) + paterno.substring(0, 2) + materno.substring(0, 2)).toUpperCase();
```